# If LN(X1) is N(0,1) but LN(X2) follows N(0,4), their Pearson correlation is -0.09<p<0.66, not -1<p<1. What's the math behind the result? Sources?

Tags: correlation, normal-distribution, pearson-r

He told me that he saw this in a book by Practical Econometrics by Carol Alexander.

Comment: This is most easily seen by examining the contrapositive: when two random variables have a correlation of $\pm 1,$ then one is a constant plus some nonzero multiple of the other (almost surely).  Since two Lognormal distributions with different geometric standard deviations do not enjoy any such relationship, they cannot possibly achieve such extreme correlations.  One way to find the achievable extremes uses [tag:copula] theory.

Comment: Several questions on site ask about the correlations between bivariate lognormals, and there are answers that detail the calculation of $\rho$. e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41734/attainable-correlations-for-lognormal-random-variables

Comment: Try searching for *lognormal correlation* which turns up multiple relevant posts